# Django: When a user profile is created automatically, what is it set to?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-users

I have a user profile which is created automatically after the User is saved:

```
def create_user_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_info, sender=User)


class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    pen_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    activated = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email + '-' + self.pen_name
```

When I create a user object with the `User.objects.create_user` function, what happens to the variables/fields in the user profile. Unless I'm mistaken, they can't be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User Profile` is no different from any other model. So it behaves exactly like how any other model would behave if you save it to database without specifying all fields. It will have empty fields.
Ofcourse in your case, since you do not allow `blank=True, null=True`, this will raise an error and require you to specify the fields.

Answer (score 1):

They're empty to start with. You can fill in the fields by manipulating `UserInfo` like any other model.

Comment: So all of the fields are allowed to be blank unlike other models?

Comment: You can allow fields in any models to be blank by passing `blank=True` or `null=True` or a combination of the two to a field in the model.